# Cannot sum property of object

Tags: javascript

I have different objects which contains this property:

```
{ products: [{ choosen: "1" }] }
{ products: [{ choosen: "2" }] }
{ products: [{ choosen: "3" }] }
```

I want sum the property `choosen`, so in this case the goal should be: 6.

What I did:

```
var total= 0;

$.each(objects, function(i, obj){
    total+= obj.products.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b.choosen;
   });
});

console.log(total);
```

this return: 0[object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Array#reduce and destructuring. Also convert string to number.

```js
const data = [{ products: [{ choosen: "1" }] },
{ products: [{ choosen: "2" }] },
{ products: [{ choosen: "3" }] }]

const res = data.reduce((a,{products})=>{
  return a+products.reduce((a2,{choosen})=>a2+Number(choosen), 0);
}, 0);

console.log(res);
```

Alternative:

```js
const data = [{ products: [{ choosen: "1" }] },
{ products: [{ choosen: "2" }] },
{ products: [{ choosen: "3" }] }]

const res = data
.map(({products})=>products)
.flat()
.reduce((a,{choosen})=>{
  return a+Number(choosen);
}, 0);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: sorry products is an array of object too.. which change I need to apply?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to convert `b.choosen` to number from string

```
return a + parseInt(b.choosen,10);
```

Comment: products is an array of object I didn't noticed that

Answer (score 0):

Using forEach loop

```js
var a = [{ products: [{ choosen: "1" }] },
{ products: [{ choosen: "2" }] },
{ products: [{ choosen: "3" }] }]

var sum=0;
a.forEach((e)=>{
sum+=Number(e.products[0].choosen)
})
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: I just saw that products is an array of objects, that's why none of the solution works how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

when you are iterating through each object there is no need to reduce the each obj, since each obj is not an array. directly you can add them up.

Here the data type of choosen was string so converted it to int using parseInt.

I hope this will solve the issue

```js
var objects = [{
    products: [{
      choosen: "1"
    }]
  },
  {
    products: [{
      choosen: "2"
    }]
  },
  {
    products: [{
      choosen: "3"
    }]
  },
]

var total = 0;

$.each(objects, function(i, obj) {
  total += parseInt(obj.products[0].choosen)
});

console.log(total);

// alternative if the choosen property changes of index

var alternativeTotal = 0;

$.each(objects, function(i, obj) {
  alternativeTotal += obj.products.reduce(function(a, b){
  return a + parseInt(b.choosen)
},0)
})

console.log(alternativeTotal)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the problem is that products is an array of object not an object, I did a mistake